# Can excessive delays in workflows cause SharePoint timer job to be stuck?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, timer-jobs

One of my workflows has excessive delays and that too of a longer duration. For instance, one delay in my workflow is of three months and other is of a single month. Now the problem is that my SharePoint timer service gets stuck and its status is "Pausing". Is it possible that the delays in workflows are causing the timer to be stuck? Has this happened to anyone before?

[This](https://docs.microsoft.com/ms-my/sharepoint/support/workflows/workflow-timer-job-is-stuck-at-pausing) article suggests that this problem can be caused by a bad workflow instance. Does my workflow come in that category?

Comment: what happens if you cancel the workflow for an item?  Does the timer job run again to start the workflow again?

Comment: Restarting/Cancelling the workflow or the timer job did not work in this case. However, apparently it is happening when the cache is full on the server that the workflow is trying to run on. Clearing the server solves the problem for the time being. However, the source of this problem still remains a point of discussion.